# What is the equivalent code for EndMenu API in c#.net

Tags: .net, winapi

I need to know the equivalent managed code that does the same as win32api call [`EndMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to close a previously shown context menu.
There is no built in way to do this. To close the currently active context menu, you can send the escape key like so:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to use `EndMenu` you need to use P/Invoke. The signature can be found on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EndMenu();
```

Comment: But i need the replacement of (EndMenu)API we use in VB to C#.NET

Comment: Thank You Daniel to share my problem.

Comment: @suresh: If you satisfied with Daniel's answer do not forget to set it as accepted